# Change the colours of a button on the basis of the selected values in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-redux

I am new to the `react js.`  I have a form which is a normal form , using simple bootstrap 3 forms. Here, I have two select

```
<form className="form-inline text-center row" role="form">
  <div className="col-xs-4">
    <div className="form-group col-xs-12">
      <label className="control-label">company/project</label>
      <select id="company" className="form-control" onChange={(event, newValue) => this.setState({ company: event.target.value, hasUserFilledCompany: true })}>
        <option disabled selected value>None Selected</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>pqr</option>
        <option>xyz</option>
        <option>cdcdc</option>
        <option>abcd</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="col-xs-4">
    <div className="form-group  col-xs-12">
      <label>Select Technology</label>
      <select id="Technology" className="form-control" onChange={(event, newValue) => this.setState({ Technology: event.target.value, hasUserFilledTech: true })}>
        <option disabled selected value>None Selected</option>
        <option>qwe</option>
        <option>gahs</option>
        <option>cdbcdbhcd</option>
        <option>cdcdc</option>
        <option>cdcbdc</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="col-xs-4">
    <div className="form-group col-xs-12" style={jobUpload}>
      <div className="row">
        <label>Job Description</label>
        <button type="button" className={"btn " + ((this.state.hasUserFilledTech && this.state.hasUserFilledCompany) ? 'enable-Button' : 'jd-button')} onClick={(event) => this.createJob(event)}>Add/Paste</button>
        <span style={or}>Or</span>
        <button type="button" className="btn jd-button">Upload File</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now, Here, what I want to do is that is user selects value from the select then buttons colour will get changed and also it will enabled. for this, my solution is I have use two variables on select as a state variable and if this becomes true then I am applying condition classes to this buttons.

This is working, But I don't think this is a proper solution to validate a form . How can I do this?

Comment: I am not clear with your question. Do you want to validate the form? or You wanna change the colour of the Upload File Button based on user selected everything or not?

Comment: 2nd one. User has selected everything or not.

Comment: This is a good solution. I don't think there is anything wrong doing this

Comment: okay will do this .

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this. A few good practise would be how you implement `onChange` function in select. You repeat a bit there. Notice how I destructured the event in `onChange` function. And You don't need another variable you can just check `!!company && company.length > 0`.

Here is the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/30yj7mrq4q

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    company: "",
    tech: ""
  }

  onChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  render() {
    const { tech, company } = this.state;
    const enabled = (!!tech && tech.length > 0) && (!!company && company.length > 0)

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <label> Company </label>
          <select name="company" onChange={this.onChange}>
            <option disabled selected value>None Selected</option>
            <option> Google </option>
            <option> Facebook </option>
            <option> Microsoft </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label> Tech </label>
          <select name="tech" onChange={this.onChange}>
            <option disabled selected value>None Selected</option>
            <option> React </option>
            <option> Angular </option>
            <option> Vue </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button className={`btn ${enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"} `} disabled={!enabled}>Upload File</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```